# Cannot get data from form with query selector

Tags: javascript, html, selectors-api

I can't get the data from the input of the form, it seems like the only function of the submit button is to refresh the page.

```js
const Form = document.querySelector('.broadcast-form')
Form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const cliente = Form.querySelector('#clienti').options[clienti.selectedIndex].text
  console.log(cliente)
})
```

```html
<form class="container broadcast-form">
  <select multiple class="form-control" id="clienti" style="height: 150px" onchange="selectCustomer()">
<!--
    <% for(var i=0; i<clienti.length; i++) {%>
      <option><%= clienti[i]["Cliente"] + " CL: " + codiceLisa[i]["Codice_Lisa"] %></option>
    <% } %>
-->
    <option>Foo CL: ABC</option>
    <option>Bar CL: DEF</option>
    <option>Baz CL: GHI</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Genera XML" />
</form>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is preventing your form from being submit. So, what's the issue?

Comment: Provide a _minimal working_ code sample reproducing the issue.

Comment: Please close your <form>

Comment: @pyrogrammer As you can see there is a lot more than just a missing end tag.

Comment: Now i've done a simplier example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the JavaScript console of your browser, you'll see that it complains about not being able to read a property of `undefined`. This is caused by `clienti` not being defined in your JavaScript code, in the `clienti.selectedIndex` part. Defining it seems to resolve your issue.

As a bonus: you may want to consider using [`selectedOptions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) to find *all* selected options in the select, given that it has the `multiple` attribute. The [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) will only give you the first one.

```js
function selectCustomer() {
  /* defined only to prevent errors when changing the value of the select */
}

const form = document.querySelector('.broadcast-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let clienti = form.querySelector('#clienti'),
      cliente = (clienti.selectedIndex < 0 ? null : clienti.options[clienti.selectedIndex].text);
  console.log(cliente);
  
  // bonus:
  for (let clienteEl of clienti.selectedOptions) {
    console.log(`bonus: ${clienteEl.text}`);
  }
})
```

```html
<form class="container broadcast-form">
  <select multiple class="form-control" id="clienti" style="height: 150px" onchange="selectCustomer()">
<!--
    <% for(var i=0; i<clienti.length; i++) {%>
      <option><%= clienti[i]["Cliente"] + " CL: " + codiceLisa[i]["Codice_Lisa"] %></option>
    <% } %>
-->
    <option>Foo CL: ABC</option>
    <option>Bar CL: DEF</option>
    <option>Baz CL: GHI</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Genera XML" />
</form>
```

Comment: thx for the answer btw i discovered that the problem was in the js another event listener was running on the same button